# How to use hotmail / email for use on holiday abroad

Tags: cellphones

I have hotmail but it can't be used abroad because of telephone verification.

I can't use my phone abroad because of international roaming charges. It would make checking email vey expensive. And it doesn't have WiFi. Also places with WiFi  expect people to have their own computers with them.

Apart from that the phone I have is not an international phone and is not compatible with some foreign systems (GSM / CDMA incompatibilities).

How can one use email when travelling around.

Comment: If you're in the US, set up Google Voice... then you can do SMS-based phone verification anywhere with a web browser.

Comment: An alternative: Use POP3/IMAP to access your hotmail account.

Comment: I think he wants to use public computers on his trip, often POP3/IMAP setups are not easy to find there.

Comment: Can't you use gmail to read POP3/IMAP?

Comment: @Flimsy, the main problem with that is that in order to use Gmail you also need an international mobile phone with roaming charges for Google's own two step verification.

Comment: @Flimsy, Google advise against this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834#gvoice

Comment: you could use mail2web.com It allows you to check pop3/imap mail through the web, no signups required

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the 2-factor authentication on your hotmail account.

Microsoft [offers a FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/two-step-verification-faq) to describe how to do it:

- Sign in to your Microsoft account.
- Because you're changing sensitive info, you might be prompted to enter a security code. Check your phone or alternate email for the code, enter it, and tap or click Submit.
- Under Password and security info, tap or click Edit security info.
- Under Two-step verification, tap or click Set up two-step verification.
- Tap or click Next, and then follow the instructions.

Comment: 1) I looked at the linked FAQ are you are quoting "
How do I turn on two-step verification?" I don't need to turn it on. It was turned on without my permission. (2) This FAQ must be out of date, it used to be optional when it first rolled out (2013) but it is now (2014) automatically on for any new device, there is no need to turn it on.

Comment: @uncovery That FAQ looks to be how to turn it **on** not how to disable it.

Comment: a quick google search offered a tutorial with screenshots http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/286925-microsoft-account-two-step-verification-turn-off.html

Comment: If you are using a smart phone / tablet, you might consider using an authenticator application (the "Google Authenticator" apps) to replace the SMS / telephone verification.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99, that was last year.

Comment: @KH.Lee, impossible with international roaming charges, these are very high for UK users, and there are also GSM / CDMA incompatibilities, so phones sold in the UK don't work in many countries.

Comment: @QuentinUK, the authenticator app does NOT require Internet access or any cellular network to operate. Your authenticator works as long as you can power on your device and the clock is correct, even in flight mode. The security code is generated by calculation. In your case, the calculation is done by Microsoft and sent via SMS. Now you just need to go through some simple steps to have your smart phone do the math by itself, "offline". You may search "Setting up Google Authenticator for Hotmail" for further information.

Comment: @KH.Lee, my mobile phone does not run apps. I want to use it when I'm on the internet to check my email, so I wonder if there's an online version because some places do not let customers install new software.

Comment: @KH.Lee, I've found the source code for the app so I'll have a look to see if I can make an online version.